# Can I ignore few static files in express static?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use('/app', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './app'), {
    maxage: '600s'
}))

app.listen(9292, function(err){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log('listening at http:localhost:9292/app');
})
```

In my code have express static for serve static files. I want to add **maxage** header for few files not to all files.

Can I add **maxage** header for few files?

```
- app
    - js
      - app.js
    - css
       - app.css
    - index.html
```

This is my app's static path. I want to add **maxage** header to all files instead of **index.html**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.url);
  if (req.url !== '/app/index.html') {
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600s')
  }
  next();
});
app.use('/app', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './app')));
```

**Method 2**

You keep your js/css/images/etc. in different sub folders. For example, perhaps you keep everything in public/, except your html files are in public/templates/. In this case, you can split it by path:

```
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')

app.use('/templates', serveStatic(__dirname + '/public/templates'), { maxAge: 0 })
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/public'), { maxAge: '1y' })
```

**Method 3**

Your files are all inter-mingled and you want to apply the 0 max age to all files that are text/html. In this case, you need to add a header setting filter:

```
var mime = require('mime-types')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')

app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/public', {
  maxAge: '1y',
  setHeaders: function (res, path) {
    if (mime.lookup(path) === 'text/html') {
      res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=0')
    }
  }
}))
```

> method 2 and 3 are copied from [github](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/issues/32)